# Are there any sports that started as a women's sport?

Tags: trivia, history, international-sports

I wonder, are there any sports that started as a women's sport and in a later period played by men (and accepted widely)?

I believe all major sports I know was initially male-oriented (or at least first few games played by men), then later women started to play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Netball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netball) as a sport was developed exclusively for women (who couldn't be expected to run in long skirts, and therefore couldn't play basketball; this is the origin of the no-running-with-ball rule).

Comment: While this is true, is netball played by men to any significant extent today? If not, it doesn't fit the criteria as defined in the question.

Comment: Men play netball, and it's widely accepted. Nothing in the question suggests men playing it is widely done, which is a separate condition altogether.

Comment: Social Netball in NZ, Aus and UK (and perhaps others) have the concept of mixed gender netball where at least 2 or 3 (out of 6 or 7) players must be from the other gender.

Answer (score 14):

[Synchronised swimming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronised_swimming) was exclusively a women's sport from its first appearance at the [World Aquatics Championships in 1973](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1973_World_Aquatics_Championships#Synchronised_swimming) until [2015 when mixed duet categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronised_swimming_at_the_2015_World_Aquatics_Championships) were introducted. The earlier (pre-1954) history of synchronised swimming does include male participation, but for many years it was a female only activity.